# Xaml Browser Application opens as a download file on client machine

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, browser, xbap

I have a Xaml browser application that I deployed on my computer. It seems to run fine and open on my computer in Internet Explorer. When I try to access it from client computer on the same network, it opens the application as a download file on Internet Explorer. I have deployed it as a full trust application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was adding the URL of my web application to the set of trusted sites and it started running on browser instead of downloading.